# Is it possible to create reference to the method?

Tags: php

I have one base class in which all actions are going. In one of this class methods i create an instance of my other own class, which is kind a helper.... In my base class i have method named `log` - purpose of this method is obvious. So is it possible somehow to pas to the helper class some reference directly to the base class log method?

Currently i have something like this:

```
class trololo {
    public function log(){
        echo __CLASS__ . ' => ' . __FUNCTION__ ."<br>\n";
    }

    private function three(){}
}

class test {

    function __construct(&$data){
        $data->log();
    }

}

class lol extends trololo {

    private function one(){}

    protected function two(){}

    public function four(){
        $this->log();

        new test($this);
    }
}

$lol = new lol;

$lol->four();
```

But as you can see i pass the full lol object to the test class, but may be it is possible to pass only `log` method?

Comment: Why would you pass a method? Why not have a logging object just for purposes of logging and share that among your classes? That way you have an object that does the logging, and that's all it does so there's no coupling nor issues such as "How do I pass a method, not the object".

Answer (score 4):

You cannot separate a method from its object. But, you can pass a [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

```
class Foo {
    public function bar() { echo 'bar'; }
}

$ref = array(new Foo, 'bar');
$ref();
```

Works since PHP 5.4, before you need `call_user_func($ref)` instead of `$ref()`.

Alternatively, use an anonymous function:

```
class Foo {
    public function bar() { echo 'bar'; }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$ref = function () use ($foo) { return $foo->bar(); };
$ref();
```

Comment: Note that @N.B.'s comment underneath the question is quite correct, this is not really a problem that needs solving. You'd typically type hint a `Log` object and use its defined interface, not pass only a method.

Answer (score -1):

Change the function to static:

```
public static function log(){
    echo __CLASS__ . ' => ' . __FUNCTION__ ."<br>\n";
}
```

So you can then just call it like this:

```
trololo::log();
```